# What are good resources for learning Numerical methods for Partial Differential Equations?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I'm having an undergraduate course on Numerical Solutions to Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations. I need online resources to supplement my study preferably videos and books. I want to build a good understanding of the subject so that I can easily apply them to fields like computer vision and robotics.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations: Finite Difference Methods , by G. D. Smith

Also, use the open courseware at:

- [*MIT Open Courseware*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-920j-numerical-methods-for-partial-differential-equations-sma-5212-spring-2003/lecture-notes/)

Comment: Meet our MSE Librarian!